# Is there a point to completing Find Mii more than twice?

Tags: streetpass-quest-find-mii

I know that you have to complete Find Mii twice to unlock Find Mii II. There is also an "accomplishment" in the StreetPass Plaza if you complete Find Mii 5 times.

Is the accomplishment the only thing I would get for completing it that many times? Or are there more things to be discovered by doing it repeatedly even after I have gotten all the hats?

Comment: Oh, I thought completing Find Mii 2 counted towards that. Maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replaying (from the third time onward) it won't unlock anything new.

If you Street Pass bunch of (the same) people frequently, you can easily get a couple of level 7 characters and some hirelings, and breeze through the game. Or save coins for puzzle pieces.